How to send an email using python which is triggered through a DevOps pipeline
Using the win32com.client as win32 package in python, I have been able to successfully send emails to my colleagues mailboxes in Outlook, which is roughly set up as below:
import win32com.client as win32

outlook = win32.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = "testemail@myemail.com"
mail.Subject = "test Subject"
mail.Body = "test body"

mail.Send()

This works fine locally, and it just sends the email using my personal address.
We also work with DevOps pipelines, and can easily call python files within our repository to facilitate Unit Testing etc, and so I was hoping to automate this email using python and calling it through a step in one of our pipelines. The script executes ok in terms of performing the necessary pre-reqs to set up the body of the email, but I get the below failure when try's to set up the outlook connection:
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\agent-04\_work\217\s\scripts\etl-daily-email.py", line 97, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\agent-04\_work\217\s\scripts\etl-daily-email.py", line 92, in main
    EmailETLDashboard()
  File "C:\agent-04\_work\217\s\scripts\etl-daily-email.py", line 70, in __init__
    outlook = win32.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
  File "c:\agent-04\_work\217\s\.conda\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 114, in Dispatch
    dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch, userName, clsctx)
  File "c:\agent-04\_work\217\s\.conda\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 100, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
    return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
  File "c:\agent-04\_work\217\s\.conda\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 82, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)

I didn't have a lot of confidence to begin with that this would work in a similar way to what it does locally. I guess my question is, is there a way of automatically sending an email, using python, that can be called within a DevOps pipeline? Pretty new to this so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

It's important to recognize that an Azure DevOps Pipeline runs on a build agent with a specific set of tools installed. Your solution works locally because you have Outlook installed and configured with the necessary credentials. You likely won't be able to use this approach on the build agent.
Here are a few possible options:

CDO: The CdoSys.dll was the library of choice for sending emails in the early 2000's, but internet security has evolved many precautions to combat span email for decades. Your mail server may reject emails from untrusted applications.

Azure DevOps REST API: The REST API has a method that can send mail, but it's primarily dedicated for sending work-items.

SendMail task: This custom task uses the PowerShell Send-MailMessage module, which is deprecated because it doesn't support the latest security protocols.

Microsoft Graph API: the Graph API has an endpoint for sending emails.


